# Setting PHP Session ID manually with the string being a defined variable

Tags: php

Am developing a student login system with PHP so i decided each student will be assigned a manually set session id based on their unique admission numbers.
So before calling `session_start`, i manually set the session id to be a string which is based on their admission numbers but this makes the whole login.php code to stop working...
`session_id("$adm");`
some of the code is indicated below

```
<?php 
$adm="CI/00119/017";
...
 if(password_verify($password,$hashed_password)){
 session_id("$adm");
session_start();
}
?>
```

Because i noticed every time i do an echo on the `session_id():`, it returns the string that was set as the session_id before the session was started. Thank You

Comment: Why does it matter what the session id is? Also, this would give everyone the same session id, which probably isn't a good idea. Session id's should be unique per user.

Comment: The PHP Session ID can only use the following range:
a-z A-Z 0-9

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php

Slashes or other special characters are not allowed. That's why it is crashing.

Comment: _Side note:_ When passing variables to functions, there's no need for the quotes. Just do: `foo($var)` instead of `foo("$var")`.

Comment: But why does ```session_id("student")``` and ```session_id("shopify")``` return different content per user when used?

Comment: its on the same browser and concurrent access could occur so each session needs to return personalized content and not to collide with others

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson, Thanks for the tip

Comment: Using the autogenerated session id's (the default behavior) will do exactly what you're asking for, give each user their own session where you can store personalized content, so I'm not really getting why you need to mess around with it at all? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: autogenererated sessions are those that are initialized with ```session_regenerate_id```?

Comment: Or just `session_start();`.

Comment: ```session_start()```is causing a session collision. I log into student A in tab 1 and then i log into student B in tab 2, i go to click on a link in in tab 1 then the system replaces session A with session B